# Do dynamic structs need to be deleted if given value from a function?

Tags: c++, struct, memory-management

Sorry if the question is hard to understand but I wasn't sure how to word it.

Say for example I had a struct like the following,

```
struct Days {
       int counter;
};
```

And in main I had

```
Days *d = new Days;
d.counter = 0;
```

If I then use `d` in a loop like this inside main

```
do {
   int num = rand()%900+1000;
   d = add(d, num);
} while(user decides to continue}
delete d;
```

where the function `add` is as follows

```
Days *add(Days *d, int num) {
      Days *temp2 = new Days;
      temp2.counter = 0;
      if (d.counter > 0)
          temp2.counter = d.counter;
      temp2.counter += num;
      return temp2;
]
```

Do I need to delete `d` after each iteration of the do-while loop since its copying over?
If so, would it be in the `add` function in the `if statement` like this

```
if (d.counter > 0) {
    temp2.counter = d.counter;
    delete d;
}
```

Or would it be in the loop in main?

Comment: You can't access `d.counter` like that, you need to dereference the pointer first (either `*d.counter` or `d->counter`). To answer you, everything you `new`ed, you must `delete` it by yourself, if you don't, your program leaks memory, no matter if the `new` is inside a function at all (so yes, you need to delete at some point what you allocated in each iteration). Lastly, I don't know why you use pointers here ? They aren't needed at all since you want a copy anyway.

Comment: @Fareanor Sorry I've been working on a project all day using both the '.' and '->' so I instinctively used the '.' Would the deallocation in the if statement be sufficient?

Comment: To give another point of view: I don't see any reason to use `new` here at all. Is this is a requirement? It would be far simpler to allocate `Days` on the stack and pass it by reference if needed.

Comment: @churill My prof is big on using only what you need but he's only shown us dynamic allocation through the use of `new`. I've heard about `malloc` and other methods but I haven't read too much about them.

Comment: @odo No it isn't, you `new`ed `temp2`, not `d` so you should `delete` the right one. But if you delete it inside the function, you can't use the returned value anymore. Finally, you can't check the value of the counter to test if you need to delete at all, it makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't need to allocate anything yourself.

In the main function, just declare your variable as:

```
// Create a Days object with counter initialized to zero
Days d {0};
```

Then, you can define your `add` function like that:

```
void add(Days & d, int num)
{
    d.counter += num;
}
```

Or if you really want to use pointers instead of references:

```
void add(Days * d, int num)
{
    d->counter += num;
}
```

Finally, you can just call it as follows:

```
do
{
    int num = whatever();
    add(d, num);
    // add(&d, num); if you used the pointer version
}
while(condition);
```

---

If I may give you an advice, since `add()` is supposed to operate on a `Days` object, it may make sense to make it a member function of `Days` so that you wouldn't need to pass a `Days` as argument and get rid of the pointers/references stuff ^^

In that case,

```
add(d, num);
```

Would become:

```
d.add(num);
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but thanks a lot! I had some UB with another part of my program and after fixing it I wanted to make sure doing something like this wouldn't create another instance of it.